# unobtrusive javascript confirm using bootstrap modal (bootbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, unobtrusive-javascript

I have a link in my MVC application:

```
<a class="btn  btn-default" confirm="Are you sure you want to delete the selected group? This action cannot be undone!" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#TabsId-5" href="/Groups/DeleteGroup/38" id="btnDelGrp"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete Selected Group</a>
```

and the following js:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
$("[confirm]").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var action = function () { alert("no action"); };
        switch ($(this).prop('tagName'))
        {
            case 'A':
                var url = $(this).attr("href");
                action = function () { document.location.href = url; };
                break;
            case 'BUTTON':
                var form = $(this).closest('form');
                if ($(this).attr("name") != "" && $(this).attr("value") != "")
                {
                    var foundIndex = $(form).attr('action').indexOf($(this).attr("name"));
                    if (foundIndex == -1) //don't add the same param over and over
                    {
                        $(form).attr('action', $(form).attr('action') + "?" + $(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).attr("value"));
                    }
                    else //else replace it
                    {
                        $(form).attr('action', $(form).attr('action').substring(0, foundIndex) + $(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).attr("value"));
                    }
                }
                action = function () { form.submit(); };
                break;
        }
        bootbox.confirm($(this).attr("confirm"), function (result) {
            if (result)
                action();
        });
    });
});
});
```

I'm having the issue where the link is firing after the dialog shows no matter what. The unobtrusive ajax doesn't seem to respect the `preventDefault`. I know there is a workaround using the `data-ajax-confirm` option, but this uses the generic js alert popup. Is there a way to get these two things to work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stop using the unobtrusive since it seems to be failing at it's primary goal: being unobtrusive!

Instead, use the [jQuery ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).  Here's a sample fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/VM4HH/

And here's the snippet of code that's making the anchor functionality work:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'a.confirm', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $tar = $(e.target);

        customConfirm($tar.data('confirm'), function() {

            var $contentTarget =  $('#' + $tar.data('custom-ajax-target-id'));

            $contentTarget.html('Loading...');

            $.ajax({
                url: $tar[0].href,
                // Following two lines for the JSFiddle demo only
                type: 'POST',
                data: { html: '<h1>' + $tar.html() + '</h1>', delay: 1 }
            }).success(function(data) {
                $contentTarget.html(data);
            });
            // You'll want to attach error handlers here to your promise
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the sample HTML:

```
<a href="/echo/html/" data-confirm="Go to Google?" data-custom-ajax-target-id="content"  class="confirm">Googs</a><br />
<a href="/echo/html/" data-confirm="Go to Yahoo?" data-custom-ajax-target-id="content" class="confirm">Yahoo</a><br />
```

Comment: I ended up modifying the original code, inspired by this post. Here's what I ended up with:

    case 'A':
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        if (!$(this).attr("ajax-replaceTargetId")) {
          action = function () { document.location.href = url; };
        }
        else {
          action = function () {
            $.ajax({
               url: url
             })
             .done(function (html) {
               $('#' + $(this).attr("ajax-replaceTargetId")).html(html);
              });
          }
        }
        break;

Comment: and for some reason I can't get that to render as code, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to hack it to say `function="return false;"`

```
<a class="btn  btn-default" confirm="Are you sure you want to delete the selected group? This action cannot be undone!" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#TabsId-5" href="#" data-href="/Groups/DeleteGroup/38" id="btnDelGrp" function="return false;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete Selected Group</a>
```

Or better, just use a data-href instead of href:

```
<a class="btn  btn-default" confirm="Are you sure you want to delete the selected group? This action cannot be undone!" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#TabsId-5" href="#" data-href="/Groups/DeleteGroup/38" id="btnDelGrp"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete Selected Group</a>
```

and js:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
$("[confirm]").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var action = function () { alert("no action"); };
        switch ($(this).prop('tagName'))
        {
            case 'A':
                var url = $(this).attr("data-href");
                action = function () { document.location.href = url; };
                break;
            case 'BUTTON':
                var form = $(this).closest('form');
                if ($(this).attr("name") != "" && $(this).attr("value") != "")
                {
                    var foundIndex = $(form).attr('action').indexOf($(this).attr("name"));
                    if (foundIndex == -1) //don't add the same param over and over
                    {
                        $(form).attr('action', $(form).attr('action') + "?" + $(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).attr("value"));
                    }
                    else //else replace it
                    {
                        $(form).attr('action', $(form).attr('action').substring(0, foundIndex) + $(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).attr("value"));
                    }
                }
                action = function () { form.submit(); };
                break;
        }
        bootbox.confirm($(this).attr("confirm"), function (result) {
            if (result)
                action();
        });
    });
});
});
```

Comment: wouldn't using data-href break everywhere I'm using non-ajax 'confirm's on 'a' tags?

Comment: It would yes but would you for them just not leave the href in? Is there a reason why non-ajax and ajax href's need to look the same?

Comment: no, they don't... so you're suggesting (pseudocode) if data-href exists, use that, else use href? The reason I'm using it in the first place is that I'm using an MVC helper-- `ActionLink`

Comment: Ah, now that makes a bit more sense (the helper part). I have honestly not tried the two together, would it be possible not to use the helper in those cases? It's 20:30 at night here and I am heading off to home but if you still haven't found the answer I will have a look at it for you in the morning?

Comment: Yes, I could just paste the HTML for the link as we've written, and toss the helper for this. I'll give it a shot and see if that works :)

Comment: unfortunately the 2nd solution has made the problem even worse. Now, it loads the entire page in the replacement target (after the modal appears), plus when I hit "OK" on the modal, it ignores the ajax altogether. I'll try your 1st idea.

Comment: 1st idea makes no difference-- still carries out the action after the modal is shown. I need a way to tell the ajax to wait for the confirmation, just like using `data-ajax-confirm`, but using my custom code...